# How to zip excel file and download in Angular7

Tags: excel, zip, angular7

How to zip excel file and download in angular7. I am trying to zip excel file and download.

Answer (score 0):

We can Use pakojs for compress the data and decompress the data. import { inflate, deflate } from 'pako';

```
datax : string = '';
fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
file: any;
deflated1: any;
public onChange(fileList: FileList): void {
this.file = fileList[0];
let fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
let self = this;
fileReader.onloadend = function(x){
self.fileContent = fileReader.result;
self.getdefleteddata(self.fileContent);   
}
this.fileReader.readAsText(this.file);
}

getdefleteddata(data, fileList){
    this.deflated1 = deflate(data);
}
```